# Why is the exception not thrown unless the returned enumerable is enumerated, and how to change this behavior?

Tags: c#, .net

Ok, I need some .Net master to tell me why the exception in the following code is only thrown once the return value is enumerated.

```cs
       public IEnumerable<string> BuildFor(Environment environment)
        {
            if (environment == Environment.None)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Impossible to build for environment '{environment}'.");
            }
            string clientId = ClientIds.Api[environment];
            foreach (string scope in scopes)
            {
                yield return $"api://{clientId}/{scope}";
            }
        }
```

Ok, correction:  I need confirmation of what's going on.  The evidence is telling me that the entire method call is being deferred, and this is, I think, a compiler optimization most likely.

The the follow up question:  How can I tell the compiler to stop doing it?

Comment: It's not an optimization, it's by design: iterator methods [use deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/yield#execution-of-an-iterator). That's just how C# works.

Comment: You should not be throwing an `Exception` there. It should be an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` or, depending on your interpretation, an `ArgumentException`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes, I think you are correct.  `ArgumentException` is the way to go.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I see.  I feared this might be the case.  Ok then, I guess I'll learn to live with it, and if not, I'll go back to creating the list in memory and returning it complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to make the actual iterator a private method called from within the method that throws the exception. The following code is much like yours and will not throw an exception until entering the second `foreach` loop in the `Main` method:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    var items = GetItems(new object());

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    items = GetItems(null);

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetItems(object obj)
{
    var items = new[] { "First", "Second", "Third" };

    if (obj == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj), "Argument cannot be null.");
    }

    foreach ( var item in items )
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

This variation works the same way as far as iteration is concerned but it will throw on the second `GetItems` call without waiting for enumeration:

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    var items = GetItems(new object());

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }

    items = GetItems(null);

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<string> GetItems(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj), "Argument cannot be null.");
    }

    return GetItemCore(obj);
}

private static IEnumerable<string> GetItemsCore(object obj)
{
    var items = new[] { "First", "Second", "Third" };

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

As suggested in the comments, if your version of C# supports it, you can use a local method instead of a private member method. It's just basically moving the private method inside the public one and removing the `private static`. This provides the same functionality but prevents that extra method being accessed anywhere else, so the public method is still self-contained, as it was originally.

```cs
public static IEnumerable<string> GetItems(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj), "Argument cannot be null.");
    }

    return GetItemsCore(obj);

    IEnumerable<string> GetItemsCore(object obj)
    {
        var items = new[] { "First", "Second", "Third" };

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In light of the impossiblity to tell the compiler to do things differently, I believe this is the best approach to obtaining the desired behavior without actually instantiating the result of the enumeration in a collection.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, tried to edit your answer but could not.  I refactored using a local function instead of creating a private implementation, which looks cleaner.  Maybe you could update your answer to use a local function?

Comment: "if your version of C# supports it": local functions were introduced in C# 7, and all currently supported versions of .NET (yes, even .NET Framework) support it. It's not really a "new" feature anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want lazy evaluation, just write the method in the "traditional" way, i.e.

```
public List<string> BuildFor(Environment environment)
{
 List<string> l = new List<string>();

 if (environment == Environment.None)
 {
     throw new Exception($"Impossible to build for environment '{environment}'.");
 }
 string clientId = ClientIds.Api[environment];
 foreach (string scope in scopes)
 {
    l.Add($"api://{clientId}/{scope}");
 }

 return l;
}
```

Or you can make sure the evaluation takes place on the spot like this:

```
List<string> l = BuildFor(Environment.Env1).ToList();
```

The compiler has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thanks.  I am well aware of this solution.  It was written like this, but I naturally refactored the previous code as a list object is not really needed.  I was hoping for an answer like a #pragma statement.  Maybe such thing doesn't exist.  Maybe this is what happens when `yield return` is used and I never noticed until now.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for stopping by and contributing.  I'll upvote your contribution, and will wait some more to see if someone comes along with my dream solution. :D

Comment: @JoséRamírez If you don't want a list and you don't want deferred execution, where do you expect the strings to "live" between the call and the enumeration?

Comment: In the smallest possible place in RAM.  A list sounds overkill.